# Updating redux state in react app.js file Authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, state

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {
  faHome,
  faClock,
  faTasks,
  faStickyNote,
  faCalendarWeek
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import { loadUser } from "./actions/authActions";

import Home from "./Home";
import SideNav from "./Components/SideNav";
import Recent from "./Components/Recent";
import TopBar from "./Components/TopBar";
import AddNote from "./AddNote";
import LogIn from "./Components/LogIn/LogIn.js";
import Register from "./Components/Register/Register";
import ToDo from "./Components/ToDo/ToDo";
import { timingSafeEqual } from "crypto";

library.add(faHome, faClock, faTasks, faStickyNote, faCalendarWeek);

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props != this.prevProps) {
      console.log("hello")
    }

  }

  LogInContainer = () => {
    return <Route path="/login" component={LogIn} />;
  };

  RegisterContainer = () => {
    return <Route path="/register" component={Register} />;
  };

  DefaultContainer = () => {
    return (
      <div className="app_container">
        <SideNav />
        <TopBar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/recent" component={Recent} />
        <Route path="/AddNote" component={AddNote} />
        <Route path="/ToDo" component={ToDo} />
      </div>
    );
  };

  // Check for authenticaition

  AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, props, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => {
          if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            return <Component {...props} />;
          } 
          else {
            return (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: "/login",
                  state: { from: this.props.location }
                }}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={this.LogInContainer} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={this.RegisterContainer} />
          <this.AuthRoute component={this.DefaultContainer} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

How can app.js receive the new state from redux after logging in? The initial fetch it will get isAuthenticated = false. User then log ins but app.js isn't getting the new state. Am I implementing authenitcation wrong? comonentDidUpdate is throwing an error when trying to update props but feel like this is a bad way of doing it anyways

Comment: You don't seem to have a mapDispatchToProps .  You need to change state through dispatching an action.

Comment: @dorriz Okay, where would I call the function to dispatch the type?

Comment: Apologise I was not clear . You should add mapDispatchToProps and use this.props.dispatch to dispatch an action.   Where ever your  login success code runs then dispatch the action from there. I cannot see where you do that but on login success you'd dispatch an action to update the isAuthenticated in your state.

Comment: @dorriz I have a function within another file that looks to see if there is an auth cookie and dispatches the type. Within the app.js file, it will mapstatetoprops, when console.logged the first state is the initial state, then a further two console.logs with the updated state of isAuth = true;